# Bootstrap 3 layout: form collapsing too soon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to get the following layout of my form using bootstrap:

```
Working on [Select field] [Select Button]
```

So: all elements are on a single row (there is plenty of space available for that).

But when I decrease the width of my browser the page switches to a weird layout as soon as it is reaching 767 pixels wide:

```
Working on

[Select field expanding over the whole row]

[Select Button]
```

While there is obviously still plenty of space to keep the form on a single row. Is there a (possibly simple) way to prevent that form to break into several lines?

I copied below the HTML page used for testing the behaviour described above :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
            <a href="#">
            Test Page
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
            You are logged in as abc@xyz.com
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">        
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label for="id_field1" class="control-label">Working on</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="id_field1" name="field1">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Select</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        Stuff will come here...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p>This is a footer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Any help and suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: As per the [grid docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) using `col-sm-*` will responsively change to vertical below 768px.

Comment: You are right Terry: this is bootstrap feature, not a malfunction or a problem with the submitted code ... Too bad that 768 pixels wide is the default breakpoint for switching to small devices, too wide in my opinion ... But that can be changed in the bootstrap config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround each item in the row with a div which has a column size class (like "col-xs-2"), like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label for="id_field1" class="control-label">Working on</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="id_field1" name="field1">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Choice 1</option>
            <option value="2">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="3">Choice 3</option>
         </select>
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Select</button>
     </div>

 </div>
```

As long as you use 'col-xs-...', every column on that row will stay on the same row even on small devices. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF2gu/2/).

EDIT:

Changing the form class to 'form-horizontal' changes the form-groups to behave as grid rows (see [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)), which allows the column sizing to stay consistent across all display sizes. [Here's a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JF2gu/4/) reflecting that change.

Comment: I am still a bit puzzled: in the fiddle you have submitted have you noticed how the form label collapses for no good reason when playing with the frame size? After having thought a long time about it I am inclined to think that this is bootstrap's normal behavior probably and that there is not much we can do about it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about how grid system works in bs3, [Bs3 grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

a brief sumary is that you have 12 columns in the width of your screen and you decide how many columns an elemnt takes when specifing these clases `col-sm-12`

this means:  (column)-(small/medium device)-(will take 12 columns)

if you are using asp, it has max width in your Site.ccs so be carefull.

check this examples [bs3 forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

I think you can try this one:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I think I was not clear enough with my explanations... In your exmpale too, can you see how the inline form switches to a stacked mode when  reducing your browser wdth to less than 768 pixels?I have spent quite some time on the docs and indeed it turns out that what I thought to be a mistake is actually a feature of bootstrap... It is ok after all, although I think that switching to small devices mode at 767 pixels wide is a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: I am not sure how, but there is surely a way to display in line forms in small devices but if you think it, it will have no sense since those fields will be really small, the fiddle of @ringstaff works take a look at that option.

Answer (score 0):

Its nice that you are OK with the way this works in Bootstrap, but I am not.
In fact, I try to avoid bootstrap form elements where this behavior is important.
I.e. I have a form with two radios and one drop-down which in xs all should fit on one line. I have wasted a full day trying to find a solution using bootstrap, before letting go of bootstrap for this specific row.
I still need to get the same look of the input fields with the other input fields however, (just not the same behavior), so thats what I will be spending the next few hours on, trying to find a match for "form-control".
View this code on XS-screen.

```
<label style="width:3.5rem;"><input class="form-control-sm" type="radio" id="Reds" name="xx" checked> Reds</label>
<label style="width:3.5rem;"><input class="form-control-sm" type="radio" id="Blues" name="xx"> Blues</label>
<select name="type" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width:7rem;">
<option value='0' selected='selected'>Shirts</option>
<option value='1'>Pants</option>
<option value='2'>Socks</option>
</select>
<button name="Find" type="submit" class="btn btn-g4 btn-sm">Find</button>
```